# Dynamic CSS and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, dynamic-data

How does one create Dynamic CSS and JavaScript On-The-Fly (using PHP).
This needs to be done as different pages have different set of elements sometimes, so wrapping and sending a large CSS/JS everytime would be overkill.
And why do many sites have link tags like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css?pg_id=43&post=62'>
```

How does the CSS come to know the GET parameters?

Since this might involve URL rewriting or using the header function, please supply short examples

Comment: I believe that this is not actual css file, it can be a page with a script that returns css, based on GET parameters. Extensions do not actually mean anything in web development.

Comment: so this would involve rewriting the URL for the CSS files?

Comment: not necessarily, it depends on style.css script, it may check session variables, cookies, etc. But yes, you will have to reload the current page in order to update your style sheets.

Comment: how can a CSS file do all that?

Comment: OrangeRind: again, it is not actual css file. It is your php script with some logic that checks database, files, variables and prints out css data according to information it gets.

Comment: because it's a server-side script that does server-side processing while serving itself as a css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there's a few different approaches you can take here. First, if you have access to apache's virtualhost files, you can set CSS to be read by a php interpreter. I've never done this and wouldnt exactly recommend it but an example is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
</VirtualHost>
```

This can also be done in your .htaccess file.

Alternatively, you can make a link like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php?pg_id=43&post=62'>
```

and put

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

as the first line.

I've never considered Vinicius' technique but I don't doubt that has its own set of advantages and disadvantages too.

PS - sometimes GET variables are uses for caching purposes (or actually to prevent caching by appending the current unix timestamp to the css link with php like

```
<link href="style.css?<?php echo time()" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: the header function is in the style.php rite?

Answer (score 2):

A request to a .css or .js file can be redirected to a PHP script using, for example, an .htaccess (in Apache), so even if the src attribute is "style.css", it's actually a PHP script that is responding to the user.

Comment: Apparently This is what I meant to ask in the first part of the question. This is the link for a wikipedia CSS, how do I do it, how do I use PHP to put CSS, do I just Echo? http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.css&amp;usemsgcache=yes&amp;

Comment: you need to specify content type header as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS and Javascript files are cached, I would not recommend serving different style sheets / js files unless they're >200KB or so in size.

And yes, you can reference any server-side page with parameters (.php or whatever extension) as long as it returns the correct Content-Type for that file.

Sidenote: Usually if you have parameters and are dynamically serving files in this manner, I believe they will not be cached automatically unless you set it up to do so.

Simple example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css.php?color=wide-red">

<?php
header('Content-Type', 'text/css; charset=utf-8');
$colorScheme = (string)$_GET['color'];

switch ( $colorScheme ) {
    case 'wide-red':
       $bgColor = 'c0c0c0';
       $fgColor = 'ffffff';
       $width = '1280px';
    break;

    case 'normal-gray':
       $bgColor = '333333';
       $fgColor = 'ffffff';
       $width = '960px';
    }
    break;

}
?>
body { 
   background:<?php echo $bgColor;?>;
   color:<?php echo $fgColor;?>;
   width:<?php echo $width;?>;
}
```

You can use echo, you can use a templating system, you can pull in other css files with file_get_contents, key thing is you need to send the right Content-Type, grab the right parameters and have a default fallback if no parameters are given.